# How to install mod on AWS (SSH) WITHOUT losing it when the instance changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

We are attempting to setup mod_pagespeed on AWS (through SSH), but came across the below message indicating that changes will be lost if a new instance is created.

```
This EC2 instance is managed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Changes made via SSH WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling.
```

I've attempted searching online for a solution to this, but am not yet fully familiar with AWS terminology - and therefore am a little lost.  Anyone have any ideas / recommendations on how to proceed?  If there's a viable option other than SSH, I'm all ears.  Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ElasticBeanstalk doc on [Customizing Software on Linux Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html), especially the Packages section.  By specifying the extra packages in EB's own config file format, these packages will be installed with each new instance, and when the environment is created.  ElasticBeanstalk provides essentially the same options as EC2 Metadata for packages, files, etc., using config files in your application version bundle.

The downside is that there is a learning curve to these config files, and getting your service configured properly is a bit different than just doing it yourself via SSH.  But it is more repeatable and in line with how ElasticBeanstalk is designed to work.

Comment: Upvoting this for now, until I have a chance to implement actual changes.  Did some brief research on setting up the package through EB's config file - feel free to elaborate on the steps there if you have any other resources - otherwise I'll mark this as the correct answer once everything has been setup.

Comment: This set me on the right track, which led to this page that shows the code side of things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066470/is-it-possible-to-use-aws-beanstalks-ebextensions-config-to-install-mod-pagesp.